# String to byte[] decoding error: no suitable method found for decode(byte[])

Tags: java, android

I decoded *Bitmap* to *String* and put ut in *SharedPreferences*.
Then I got it and put it in `PhotoEncoded`
Here I want to decode it as byte[], but it's showing me an error:

```
String PhotoEncoded = prefs.getString("AccountPhotoString",null);
              byte[] b = PhotoEncoded.getBytes();
              byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(b);//error
```

What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
PhotoEncoded = prefs.getString("AccountPhoto",null);
          byte[] b = PhotoEncoded.getBytes();
          byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(b,Base64.DEFAULT);
```